# Mentioning someone in a comment to attract his/her attention to the question

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

If I mention someone in my comment with @user and that user is not part of the discussion, will he/she receive the notification?

Comment: No, of course not. How annoying would that be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, they won't.

Only the people who edited the post and commented on it will be notified.

See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/140505) for details.

Comment: Any idea why just moderators and not mortal close voters?

Comment: @Dennis - Probably on account of up to 5 mortal closers. If one wants to notify a closer, it should be on that _can do something about it_ and only diamond moderators can.

Comment: Makes sense. 5 times `Why the close vote?` sounds like noise.

Comment: So what's the acceptable way to draw someone's attention to a question I believe they are well qualified to answer?

Comment: @malenkiy_scot - Someone specific? You don't do it on the network.

Answer (score 1):

## No

Unless:

1. They've edited the post in question
2. They're a moderator and they closed the question.

More info: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)