# What are legitimate ways to attract attention to a question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12060061/1614925) which got prompt responses,and led me to ask a follow up question.
However my [newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12072461/1614925) doesn't seem to have attracted any answers or even comments.

I'm wondering what to do next to attract some attention to it.
I was thinking about posting a comment and using @user  to notify users who had answered the previous question but [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131372/194032) seems to suggest that is inappropriate .Answers to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/194032) on meta also gives good advice but in my opinion  it doesn't apply fully to  my situation

Comment: I think that [the question you link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) applies perfectly fine. Why doesn't it?

Comment: @Bart I think the difference is that my question has not received any answers at all whereas the other question had received answers which were not selected(ostensibly it received more attention at a point in time,mine does not seen to have manged to do that).

Also my question is related to another question which had been dully answered,my thinking is that the new question is as relevant as the first and that users who had been able to input to that one would be able to help with this new one

Comment: You want attention for your unanswered question. Update it to improve it (so it's bumped) or add a bounty once you have sufficient reputation to do so. There's really not much more to it.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple ways

- Start a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/167443)
- Post a link on Twitter/Faccebook/Google+/etc.
- Make sure it is properly [tagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/167443)
- Make a constructive edit to improve the quality of the questions (readability, detail, relevance)
- Make sure the title succinctly describes the problem. Do not attach tags to the title, as it is redundant to do so and gets in the way of reading the actual title.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot start a bounty with my current no of points,so I would really appreciate it if you cold post a comment on which aspects of the question could be improved

Comment: Have added a comment suggesting a way that you can improve the question by providing some more precise information. That should help people to better understand what the actual issue is and figure out a solution.